# Why i used synchronized list and still get ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, concurrency, thread-safety

I have found a same question in [I used synchronized list, and i still get ConcurrentModificationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437799/i-used-synchronized-list-and-i-still-get-concurrentmodificationexception), but i didn't find a correct answer.

Here is how i defined my `synchronized` list:

```
private List<ActionItemClickListener> actionItemClickListeners = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ActionItemClickListener>());
```

And here is how i used it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    boolean isConsume = false;
    synchronized (actionItemClickListeners) {
        //ConcurrentModificationException occur here
        for (ActionItemClickListener listener : actionItemClickListeners) {
            isConsume = isConsume | listener.onSystemBackPressed();
        }
    }
    if(!isConsume) {
        pendingFragment = null;
        pendingTag = null;
        currentFragmentTag = null;
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
public void addActionItemClickListener(ActionItemClickListener listener) {
        synchronized (actionItemClickListeners) {
            if (listener != null)
                actionItemClickListeners.add(listener);
        }
}

public void removeActionItemClickListener(ActionItemClickListener listener) {
        synchronized (actionItemClickListeners) {
            if (listener != null)
                actionItemClickListeners.remove(listener);
        }
}
```

**Why i'm still getting `ConcurrentModificationException`???**

Comment: Can you tell us where do you get the exception? Also, what is `super.onBackPressed();`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani, is an android callback, invoked by the os when the back button is pressed

Comment: @ReutSharabani i commented in code, `super.onBackPressed()` is a super call, my class extends from `Activity` class.

Comment: @mr.icetea did you try a regular `for` loop instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397321/why-does-one-loop-throw-a-concurrentmodificationexception-while-the-other-doesn

Comment: are you accessing `actionItemClickListeners` somewhere else ?

Comment: @Blackbelt no, only 3 functions above.

Comment: would you mind posting the whole stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: What does `listener.onSystemBackPressed();` do?  It is possible that it is calling `addActionItemClickListener` or `removeActionItemClickListener`?

Comment: @pathfinderelite yes it some time trigger `removeActionItemClickListener`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-despite-using-synchronized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ConcurrentModificationException` is not a thread issue.  It is thrown because you are modifying a list while iterating through it.

```
for (ActionItemClickListener listener : actionItemClickListeners) {
    isConsume = isConsume | listener.onSystemBackPressed();
}
```

The problem is that `listener.onSystemBackPressed();` is calling `removeActionItemClickListener`, which attempts to change the `actionItemClickListeners` which you are in the process of iterating through.  Trying to change a list that you are iterating through will cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`

**How to fix**

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can only guess as to how to fix this, but you could use `iterator.next()`, `iterator.hasNext()` and `iterator.remove()` for looping through and removing the the listener, respectively.  You would either need to pass the `iterator` through `onSystemBackPressed()` and `removeActionItemClickListener`, which is a little ugly, or have `onSystemBackPressed()` return a boolean value indicating if it should remove the listener.

```
final Iterator<String> iterator = actionItemClickListeners.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    final String listener = iterator.next();
    final boolean removeListener = listener.onSystemBackPressed();
    if (removeListener) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
    isConsume = isConsume | removeListener;
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like you are using the return value of `onSystemBackPressed()` for something else, so that may not work either.

Comment: Thank for your explanation. Can you help me find a solution for my case?

Comment: @mr.icetea  Added possible solution to answer.  However, it's hard to say if it will be helpful without having more detail.  In any case, you can use `Iterator` like above to remove from the list while iterating through it, so that will hopefully help lead you to a solution.