# Stuck with "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Tags: java, exception, linked-list, concurrentmodification

Here is my code:

```
// eventList is a LinkedList

public void run() {

    Iterator<Event> it = eventList.iterator();
    int size = eventList.size();

    while(size > 0) {
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Event e = it.next(); //flaged line

            if(e.ready()) {
                System.out.println(e);
                e.action();
                eventList.remove(e);
                --size;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown at the flag lined (`Event e = it.next();`). Do you see a mistake in my code that makes obvious the reason of that exception to be thrown?

Comment: possible duplicate of [loop on list with remove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921104/loop-on-list-with-remove)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your are modifying `eventList` while using `eventList.remove()` while iterating over it. You must not do this, or the `Iterator` becomes unusable.

Simply replace `eventList.remove(e)` with `it.remove()` and it should be fine.

Also, you can easily run into an endless loop if one of your events isn't ready in the first run because `it.hasNext()` will never return `true` once it returned `false`, but `size` won't be modified either. One solution would be to move the whole `Iterator it = ...` line *inside* the first `while` loop.

I'd also modify the outer `while` loop to use `while (!e.isEmpty())` instead of trying to track the size of `eventList` manually.

Comment: +1 for this answer; just a note, this problem is described in the docs for that exception:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: Thank you. I think that the problem was that I looked to much time at code:) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the element through the iterator, otherwise the iterator gets reset because the underlying collection changed.