# What is wrong with this foreach loop..??? Android

Tags: java, android

I have a foreach loop iterating through each object in a vector. When I debug the code, it runs successfully for the first object in the vector. But then it will fail when it tries to run the loop for the second object. I am *sure* there is more than one element in the vector.

```
for(Object shape : vecForShapes)
        {
            currentNode = (Drawable) shape;
             newNode = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nodered);
             newNode.setBounds(currentNode.getBounds());
             vecForShapes.remove(currentNode);
              vecForShapes.add(newNode);
        }
```

So basically my question is, why is this loop failing? I really do not understand what is wrong here.

P.S. My final aim is to remove `currentNode` from the vector, replace it with `newNode` then redraw the whole vector in my `onDraw` method.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean: it fails? Do you get an Exception?

Comment: This probablyis your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080208/java-exception-when-remove-a-record-inside-a-list-in-a-for-each-loop

Comment: Please show the definition of your vecForShapes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not remove or add objects from/to a collection you iterate on. `vecForShapes.remove(currentNode);` for instance modifies `vecForShapes`. Thus you get  your exception.

If I were you I would have done the modification you want like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vecForShapes.size(); i++) {
     currentNode = (Drawable) shape;
     newNode = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nodered);
     newNode.setBounds(currentNode.getBounds());
     vecForSahpes.set(i, newNode);
}
```

This should do what you want without any error.

PS: do you really mean `Vector`? I seriously recommend using `ArrayList` instead. It is significantly better performant.

Comment: Vector is better when data increases exponentially and it is thread safe. But yes most of other cases I will use ArrayList too

Comment: Thanks a lot you were correct....I didn't know I could not remove or add from a collection when iterating...

I will definately take a look now at arraylist...thanks for the tips!!

Answer (score 1):

When using `foreach` on an `Iterable`, there would be an `Iterator` behind the scenes and you can not modify a Collection when iterating over it, but you can call "iterator.remove()". So I recommend you to use old iteration model `for (Iterator i = v.iterator(); i.hasNext(); .....` and call the `i.remove()` on it.