# How can i counter a ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, for-loop, concurrentmodification

if have the following problem: 
I have a List which i am going through using the enhanced for loop. Every time i want to remove sth, out of the list, i get a ConcurrentModificationException. I already found out why this exception is thrown, but i don`t know how i can  modify my code, so that its working. This is my code:

```
for(Subject s : SerData.schedule)
    {
        //Checking of the class is already existing
        for(Classes c : s.classes)
        {
            if(c.day == day &c.which_class == which_class)
            {
                int index = getclassesindex(s.classes, new Classes(day, which_class));
                synchronized (s) {
                    s.classes.remove(index);

                }
            }
        }
            //More code....
    }
```

I also tried out this implementation.

```
for(Subject s : SerData.schedule)
    {
        //Checking of the class is already existing
        Iterator<Classes> x = s.classes.iterator();
        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            Classes c = x.next();
            if(c.day == day &c.which_class == which_class)
            {
                int index = getclassesindex(s.classes, new Classes(day, which_class));
                synchronized (s) {
                    s.classes.remove(index);
                }
            }
        }
        //More code....
    }
```

not working either...

Is there a common used, standard solution? (Hopefully sth. that is not obvious :D )

Comment: Did you miss type your copied code or did you mean to have a bitwise and in your if statement (ie, single &), I think you should have &&

Comment: i had &&, was a mistype...sry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason this issue occurs is because of the semantic meaning of your for-each loop.

When you use for-each loops, the data structure that is being traversed **cannot** be modified.

Essentially anything of this form will throw this exception:

```
for( Object o : objCollection )
{
    // ...
    if ( satisfiesSomeProperty ( o ) )
       objList.remove(o);    // This is an error!!
    // ...
}
```

As a side note, you can't add or replace elements in the collection either.

There are a few ways to perform this operation.

One way is to use an iterator and call the `remove()` method when the object is to be removed.

```
Iterator <Object> objItr = objCollection.iterator();

while(objItr.hasNext())
{
    Object o = objItr.next();
    // ...
    if ( satifiesSomeProperty ( o ) )
        objItr.remove();    // This is okay
    // ...
}
```

This option has the property that removal of the object is done in time proportional to the iterator's `remove` method.

The next option is to store the objects you want to remove, and then remove them after traversing the list. This may be useful in situations where removal during iteration may produce inconsistent results.

```
Collection <Object> objsToRemove = // ...
for( Object o : objCollection )
{
    // ...
    if ( satisfiesSomeProperty ( o ) )
       objsToRemove.add (o);
    // ...
}
objCollection.removeAll ( objsToRemove );
```

These two methods work for general `Collection` types, but for lists, you could use a standard for loop and walk the list from the end of the list to the front, removing what you please.

```
for (int i = objList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Object o = objList.get(i);
    // ...
    if ( satisfiesSomeProperty(o) )
       objList.remove(i);
    // ...
}
```

Walking in the normal direction and removing could also be done, but you would have to take care of how incrementation occurs; specifically, you don't want to increment `i` when you remove, since the next element is shifted down to the same index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++)
{
    Object o = objList.get(i);
    // ...
    if ( satisfiesSomeProperty(o) )
    {
       objList.remove(i);
       i--;
    }

    //caveat: only works if you don't use `i` later here
    // ...
}
```

Hope this provides a good overview of the concepts and helps!

Comment: thx, that overview is better than the top google results :D Thank you...

but, i thought that iterator's remove method is just removing it out of the iterator and not out of the collection.
I think i am wrong, but i am not sure....is it?

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner; for the completeness of the post I'll respond to your first question. The behavior of an iterator's `remove` method should be to remove the last-seen object *from the underlying data structure you are iterating*.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Iterator.remove()` should prevent the exception from being thrown.

Comment: Agreed, possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921104/loop-on-list-with-remove

Comment: Keep in mind that `Iterator.remove()` is an optional operation, much like `List.remove(int)`, although I suspect that the core Java collections implement it correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Hm if I get it right you are iterating over a collection of classes and if a given class matches some criteria you are looking for the its index and try to remove it?

Why not just do:

```
Iterator<Classes> x = s.classes.iterator();
while(x.hasNext()){
    Classes c = x.next();
    if(c.day == day && c.which_class == which_class) {
        x.remove();
    }
}
```

Add synchronization if need be (but I would prefer a concurrent collection if I were you), preferably change the "==" to equals(), add getters/setters etc. Also the convention in java is to name variables and methods using camelCase (and not separating them with "_").

Actually this is one of the cases when you *have* to use an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for `Collection` subclasses in general - most iterators will become invalid if the collection is modified, *unless* the modification happens through the iterator itself via [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29).

There *is* a potential solution when it comes to [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations: the `List` interface has index-based [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29)/[get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29)/[set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29)/[remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) operations. Rather than use an `Iterator` instance, you can iterate through the list explicitly with a counter-based loop, much like with arrays. You should take care, however, to update the loop counter appropriately when inserting or deleting elements.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc on ConcurrentModificationException:

"if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception."

So within your 
    for (Classes c : s.classes)

you are executing 
    s.classes.remove(index)

and the iterator is doing just what its contract says.  Declare the index(es) in a scope outside the loop and remove your target after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<Classes> classesIterator = s.classes.iterator();
while (classesIterator.hasNext()) {
    Classes c = classesIterator.next();
    if (c.day == day && c.which_class == which_class) {
        classesIterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for-each iterator is fail-fast and this is why remove operation fails as it would change the collection while traversing it.

What implementation of List interface are you using? 
Noticed synchronisation on Subject, are you using this code concurrently?

If concurrency is the case, then I would recommend using [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). It doesn't need synchronisation and its for-each iterator doesn't throw ConcurrentModificationException.