# Better way to loop through the List<String> and remove items

Tags: java

I have a List and I'm looping through it removing items in the List if there is a match.
I'm using i = -1 if the item in the List is removed. But it loops through from the beginning again. Is there a better way to do this?

```
private List<String> populateList(List<String> listVar) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("2015-01-13 09:30:00");
    list.add("2015-01-13 06:22:12");
    list.add("2015-01-12 05:45:10");
    list.add("2015-01-12 01:52:40");
    list.add("2015-01-12 02:23:45");
    return list;
}

private void removeItems() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list = populateList(list);  
    System.out.println("List before modification : "+list);
    for (int i = 0; i <  list.size(); i++) {
        String dateNoTime = list.get(i).split(" ")[0];
        System.out.println("   Going over : "+list.get(i));
        if(!dateNoTime.equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13")) {
            System.out.println("      Removing : "+list.get(i));
            list.remove(i);
            i = -1; //This is making the loop start from scratch. Is there a better way?
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("List after modification: "+list+"\n\n");
}
```

Comment: am I missing something? why can't you just remove the part `i = -1`?

Comment: Should be a concurrent modification exception!? Use an Iterator instead.

Comment: just loop in reverse direction. (from end to begining)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating through a list, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)

Comment: @SOfanatic : because the elements inside the list are removed and the list is altered. So the position of the item in the list has changed

Comment: This question is duplicate at least of 2 other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921104/loop-on-list-with-remove?rq=1

Comment: @jp-jee There is no `ConcurrentModificationException` here because he's using a `for` loop with an integer index.  `ConcurrentModificationException` comes up when you have something like `for (String s : list)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's `List<T>` provides a better way of removing items from it by using `ListIterator<T>`:

```
ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String s = iter.next();
    String dateNoTime = s.split(" ")[0];
    if(!dateNoTime.equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13")) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Iterator interface which has remove method.

```
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        String next = iterator.next();
        String dateNoTime = next.split(" ")[0];

        if(!dateNoTime.equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13")) {
            System.out.println("      Removing : "+next);
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java-8, you can simplify the entire thing to:

```
List<String> filtered = list.stream().filter(item -> item.split(" ")[0]
                                                         .equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13"))
                                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think this is the shortest way to remove items from the list by checking them one-by-one. (I mean 'shortest' in terms of code size, not complexity-wise).

Answer (score 1):

When you're using an index to iterate through a list, and you're removing items from the list, you need to be careful about how you handle the index.  (Doing the `remove` through the iterator as in @dasblinkenlight's answer is better in this case, but there are other similar situations where it's not possible.)

Suppose you just deleted the line that resets `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  list.size(); i++) {
    String dateNoTime = list.get(i).split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println("   Going over : "+list.get(i));
    if(!dateNoTime.equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13")) {
        System.out.println("      Removing : "+list.get(i));
        list.remove(i);
        //i = -1; //This is making the loop start from scratch. Is there a better way?
    }   
}
```

Now, when `i==2`, you decide you need to remove the element.  When you do so, the item that was element 3 then becomes element 2, and the element that was element 4 then becomes element 3, and so on.

**But** then you go back up to the top and increment `i`.  It is now 3.  The result is that the element that **was** element 3, but is now element 2, is never examined at all.  It gets skipped.

There are a couple ways to deal with this.

One is to make sure `i` doesn't get incremented.  I've seen good programmers do things like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  list.size(); i++) {
    String dateNoTime = list.get(i).split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println("   Going over : "+list.get(i));
    if(!dateNoTime.equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13")) {
        System.out.println("      Removing : "+list.get(i));
        list.remove(i);
        i--;   // Move "i" backwards so that no elements are skipped
    }   
}
```

Personally, I dislike modifying an index inside a `for` loop like this, so I'd be happier with

```
int i = 0;
while (i < list.size()) {
    String dateNoTime = list.get(i).split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println("   Going over : "+list.get(i));
    if(!dateNoTime.equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13")) {
        System.out.println("      Removing : "+list.get(i));
        list.remove(i);
    } else {
        i++;   
    }   
}
```

[Note that in both cases, it's important to use `list.size()` in the termination condition, and not save the original value in a variable.  The list size will change, and you want to use the new size when checking for termination.]

Another solution that may be appropriate in some cases is to go backward through the list:

```
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    String dateNoTime = list.get(i).split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println("   Going over : "+list.get(i));
    if(!dateNoTime.equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13")) {
        System.out.println("      Removing : "+list.get(i));
        list.remove(i);
    } 
}
```

which doesn't have the problem when elements are shifted.

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterators.

Javadoc for Iterator says the following

Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use guava API to achieve it.

```
FluentIterable
       .from(list)
       .transform(new Function<String, String>(){
           @Override
           public void apply(String input){
               return input.split(" ")[0];
           }
       }).filter(new Predicate<String>(){
           @Override
           public boolean apply(String input){
               return input.equalsIgnoreCase("2015-01-13");
           }
       }).toList();
```