# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException on recursive iterator based removal from LinkedList?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I've been trying to efficiently create trees by assigning a child to its parent and then deleting it via `it.remove()`:

```
for (OgOrganizationTreeDTO parent : parents) {
    setChildren(parent, organizationTree);
}
```

Here is the implementation of the `setChildren` function

```
private void setChildren(OgOrganizationTreeDTO root, List<OgOrganizationTreeDTO> allOrganizations) {
    if (allOrganizations.isEmpty()) {
        return ;
    }
    Iterator<OgOrganizationTreeDTO> it = allOrganizations.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        OgOrganizationTreeDTO potentialChild = it.next();
        if (potentialChild.getIdParentId() != null && potentialChild.getIdParentId().equals(root.getId())) {
            root.addChild(potentialChild);
            it.remove();
            setChildren(potentialChild, allOrganizations);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a LinkedList and I get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. I've solved the problem by passing a copy of `allOrganizations` to the recursive `setChildren` function like so `new LinkedList<>(allOrganizations)`, but the copy part takes `O(n)` time and I don't want that.

I've also tried using `LinkedBlockingQueue`, but I've found out that deletion takes `O(n)` time.

I want to take advantage of `LinkedList` `O(1)` remove, so everytime I add a child, and recur on it the list becomes smaller.

I've also successfully implemented a solution with `HashSet` by marking individual nodes as seen, and setting the base case to `hashSet.size() == allOrganizations.size()`, but I still keep recurring over the same size List, so this doesn't help me other.

Is there any way of accomplishing my goal of using `LinkedList` `O(1)` remove, or is there an even more **efficient alternate** approach to this ?

Comment: You can try using a `ListIterator`

Comment: Or if you worry about performance you can do it without recursion - use a big hashmap to store all processed entites and you can do it with 2 iterations on the list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loop on list with remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921104/loop-on-list-with-remove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know how to do it with recursion because you actually create a new iterator in each recursive call  (allOrganizations.iterator() - creates new iterator instance). So when you do call delete you modify the collection for the other iterators and that's why it throws that exception.

- One solution would be to use some CopyOnWriteList which allows concurrent modification but it is just passing a copy of the list, not modifying the same one so it will take additional memory.
- Another solution would be to add some property to  OgOrganizationTreeDTO class that marks if that row is already processed. In this case instead of deleting the item from the list you will just mark it as processed.
- But anyway since you are asking about performance and the big O then I can offer you another solution which has O(n) complexity. Of course there is some tradeoff with more  memory used but that is the standard memory vs complexity problem...

  ```
  private static void setChildrenMap(OgOrganizationTreeDTO root, 
       List<OgOrganizationTreeDTO> allOrganizations) {

    Map<Integer, OgOrganizationTreeDTO> organizationsMap = new HashMap<>();
    organizationsMap.put(root.getId(), root);

    for (OgOrganizationTreeDTO element : allOrganizations) {
      organizationsMap.put(element.getId(), element);
    }

    for (OgOrganizationTreeDTO element : allOrganizations) {
       organizationsMap.get(element.getParentId()).addChild(element);
    }

  }
  ```

Basically taking an element from the hashmap is a constant time so we are using that to find the required parent. You might need to add some checks if you expect elements with bad data because `organizationsMap.get(element.getParentId())` might return null

Comment: Thank you. Very elegant solution indeed.